# Amazon Prime Video Android App (Mod Version from divyanet.com) Analysis

Tags: android, video-streaming, malware

Seeking any kind of advice/input from this community.

Background Story:

I came across an cracked Amazon Prime Video Android App on divyanet.com (It claims it's the cracked version of the Original Amazon Prime Video Android App. Same movie selections and everything minus paying for the subscription)

I installed it and realized it was a different app in the way that it wasn't the actual Amazon Prime cracked.

To confirm my suspicion. I set up an Environment to capture the cracked app's network traffic.
I ran Genymotion (Android Simulator) and Burp Suite on the same laptop. I proxied the Android instance traffic to that of the laptop's so Burp Suite could capture it.

What I saw was a good learning experience. This cracked app was sending Get requests all over the place. (To many free movies/shows domains and some domains are even being marked as malicious)

Examples:

> tovanillitechan.com (Https://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-tovanillitechan-com/)
> tzegilo.com (https://hybrid-analysis.com/sample/6d9faaedd7dd72dc8e0da476e0af4b08d6ca24bf60b498d20e070f90f1b45af1/62aa234f35008f214f1869ac)
> unphionetor.com (https://any.run/report/7974be8113970f143fd17339a5c349d499a05ccf99c940b34979f38d283bb1b3/99008e10-24bd-4cb1-aa59-ab8d5baaf0d0)

My questions are: (See links for HTTP Get and response details)
`enter code here`[Request Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3kw5.png)
`enter code here`[Response Header-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fxj68.png)
`enter code here`[Response Header-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wx5Jh.png)

A: How is the site owner benefitting from tricking users downloading this supposedly cracked app?
(While streaming the movies, there isn't even ads interrupting the movies)

B: I haven't noticed my phone acting weird like slowness or random ads pop up. How can I check to see if anything malicious installed? What are the typical reason for this cracked app calling out to these malicious domains?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Because the app is a trojan and he now has complete control of your device.  Some of those malicious requests are likely to command and control servers.  Please tell me you didn't use your actual phone, because if so he has access to anything your app had access to, including your email, online banking, etc.

Don't try to figure out what he may have changed.  You don't have the skillset for it.  Factory reset the device immediately.  Even that isn't a 100% sure fix, if you have another device I'd switch to that.  And stop downloading cracks, it's a horrible idea.  You're taking something from skilled hackers and reverse engineers and running it on your device, and just hoping that someone who has no problem with cracking an app would somehow draw the line at putting a keylogger in there.  Hint:  they won't.

Comment: Hello Gabe, 

Thank you for the input! 

2 Follow up questions as I saw how much experience you have. 

1. Virus total has scanned the apk file and came back clean. (My thought process is that all Virus total did was a static analysis, it didn't execute the apk in a dynamic environment. Therefore, it wouldn't detect all those call outs.) Is this true? 

2. Could you kindly point me to the right direction as to see what has been installed on my phone? I am really interested in this malware analysis field and would like to learn more.